# Android View: Dimension change callback

Tags: android, android-view, android-custom-view

I'm wondering if there are callbacks that are triggered on a Views dimension change.

The auto generated custom views for Android Studio have code like this in the onDraw():

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    paddingLeft = getPaddingLeft();
    paddingTop = getPaddingTop();
    paddingRight = getPaddingRight();
    paddingBottom = getPaddingBottom();

    contentWidth = getWidth() - mPaddingLeft - mPaddingRight;
    contentHeight = getHeight() - mPaddingTop - mPaddingBottom;
    ...
}
```

This seems like a waste to keep recalculating these paddings and content widths if most of the time they will not change. I'm looking for a `Callback` that will only update these values if they change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be looking for [`onSizeChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)):

> This is called during layout when the size of this view has changed. If you were just added to the view hierarchy, you're called with the old values of 0.
>
> Parameters
> w  Current width of this view.
> h  Current height of this view.
> oldw   Old width of this view.
> oldh   Old height of this view.

This won't help with padding changes, though. You'd still need to check them, or also override `setPadding()` and recalculate there.

Comment: Thanks just what I was looking for! Too bad it's not the default generated code for Android Studio.